# 'securestorage' does not contain a definition for setasync

Tags: xamarin

Following this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

I have installed Xamarin.Essentials and added `using Xamarin.Essentials;` as instructed but it is not in used.

I got this error: `'securestorage' does not contain a definition for setasync`

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Xamarin_SQLite.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SecureStorage : ContentPage
{
    public SecureStorage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {

            SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'securestorage' does not contain a definition for setasync

1) Your class name for the page is `SecureStorage` and that is where the error is coming from.

Change the class name and|or fully qualify the call to:

```
`Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.SetAsync`
```

or create a `using` alias for `Xamarin.Essentials` and qualify the static method with that alias)

2) You need to **`await`** that call:

```
 `await Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.SetAsync...`
```

Comment: @Steve It is an `async` method....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async